# Application of existence and uniqueness of measure

Tags: measure-theory

I have the following situation: $\Omega$ is a finite set, $A$ a sigma-algebra on it. Suppose I have a finite partition of $\Omega$ into pairwise disjoint subsets $\pi_i$, such that I can write every $B\in A$ as a (finite) union of $\pi_i$'s. Now I want to show that there is a unique measure on $A$ such that $\mu(\pi_i)=p_i$ for given $p_i$.
 My argument was, that since $\{\cap_{i\in I}\pi_i\}$ is a $\cap$-stable generator of $A$, defining a $[0,1]$-valued, additive function on it will have at most one extension to $A$ which is a measure (by a theorem I forgot the name of). But since $A$ is also an algebra, defining $\mu(\cup\pi_i)=\sum p_i$ gives us the existence of a measure by Carathéodorys theorem. Is it really that easy in the finite case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is that easy.

But in fact, it is even more easy. As each set $B \in A$ is of the form $B =\biguplus_{i \in I_B} \pi_i$ for a suitable (unique, finite) subset $I_B \subset I$, we must have

$$
\mu(B)=\sum_{i \in I_B} \mu(\pi_i) =\sum_{i \in I_B} p_i, \qquad (\dagger)
$$

which yields uniqueness of $\mu$ (even only under the assumption that $\mu$ is finitely additive.

Also, it is straightforward to show that if we **define** $\mu$ as in $(\dagger)$, then it is already countable additive (simply observe that if $B =\biguplus_{n} B_n$, then already $B_n=\emptyset$ for all but finitely many $n$, because you are working on a finite set).

Hence, you do not need to invoke the abstract uniqueness theorem or Caratheodory's theorem.